SSRS (version 2018.0150.1103.12) Cannot connect to Reporting Server - Times out
Trying to connect to SSRS (version in title) either directly through the browser (http://(computername)/ReportServer) or through SSRS Configuration Manager. In Config manager the spinning cursor shows but I never get an error message and I am unable to go any further.
In the browser, it eventually times out and I get the following error.
Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out 
I made sure SQL Services were running and that I can see and connect to the Reporting Services databases through SSMS, and I can.
I tried restarting Reporting Services and I also tried upgrading SSRS to see if a configuration issue might be corrected. Nothing changed.
At this point, I'm thinking I need to uninstall and reinstall, but I'm hoping this is might be an easy fix either through the Registry or some other configuration settings.
